# Add value (Array) in database

Tags: php

I tried this code but it does not work for me. i just want to add the array value to database. it give me error like this

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2

Here is my code:

```
$timeadd = date("m-d-Y H:i:s", strtotime('+6 hours'));      

$extinvoice=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from invoice WHERE BRANCH_CODE_MX='".$display_branchcode."' and INVOICE_NO_MX='".$invoicecode."' and INVOICE_ITEM_UNIT_MX='EXTENDEDWARRANTY'");
while($extrow=mysqli_fetch_array($extinvoice))
{
    $ewtitemcode=$extrow["INVOICE_ITEM_CODE_MX"];
    $imeiserialunit=$extrow["EWT_IMEI_MX"];
    $customercode=$extrow["INVOICE_CUS_CODE_MX"];
    $ewtarray[] = "('$invoicecode','$ewtitemcode', '$imeiserialunit','$customercode','$display_branchcode','$timeadd')";

}
$arrayitem=count($ewtarray); 

for($item = 0; $item <= $arrayitem; $item++)
{
    $sql = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO extended_warranty
        (INVOICE_NO_MX,FORM_EW_MX,EW_SERIAL_MX,CUSTOMER_CODE,BRANCH_CODE_MX,DATE_ADDED)
        VALUES
        ($ewtarray[$item])");

}
```

Comment: use `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: on what "line"?

Comment: Looks like a perfect senario for preparing a statement once and executing it many times binding new values to the parameters each time round the loop

Comment: @fantaghirocco i use that and the error disappear but it doesnt add value in database

Comment: your query probably failed then; check for errors and/or see @RiggsFolly 's answer below.

Comment: when i use this $ewtitemcode=$extrow["INVOICE_ITEM_CODE_MX"];
  $imeiserialunit=$extrow["EWT_IMEI_MX"];
    $formserial=$extrow["INVOICE_ITEM_SERIAL_MX"];
    $customercode=$extrow["INVOICE_CUS_CODE_MX"];
          $ewtarray[] = "(
    '$invoicecode'
    )";

Comment: $sql = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO extended_warranty
  ( INVOICE_NO_MX)
  VALUES
  ($ewtarray[$item])");

Comment: it only works when  ihave one variable and one value declare

Answer (score 0):

The database requires a datatime in the format

```
2016-10-02 10:00:00
```

So change this

```
$timeadd = date("m-d-Y H:i:s", strtotime('+6 hours'));
```

to

```
$timeadd = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+6 hours'));
```

Comment: The anticipation is kind of killing me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Phew I can breath again

Comment: it only works when ihave one variable and one value declare but if i include all value and variables its not working

Comment: I have to say its probably easier to use a `INSERT SELECT` query than it is to fix what you are currently doing

Answer (score -1):

Additionally to the other users I have removed the double brackets. What happens now?

```
$timeadd = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+6 hours'));     

$extinvoice=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from invoice WHERE BRANCH_CODE_MX='".$display_branchcode."' and INVOICE_NO_MX='".$invoicecode."' and INVOICE_ITEM_UNIT_MX='EXTENDEDWARRANTY'");
while ($extrow=mysqli_fetch_array($extinvoice)) {
    $ewtitemcode=$extrow["INVOICE_ITEM_CODE_MX"];
    $imeiserialunit=$extrow["EWT_IMEI_MX"];
    $customercode=$extrow["INVOICE_CUS_CODE_MX"];
    $ewtarray[] = "('$invoicecode','$ewtitemcode', '$imeiserialunit','$customercode','$display_branchcode','$timeadd')";
}

for ($item = 0; $item < count($ewtarray); $item++) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO extended_warranty
        (INVOICE_NO_MX,FORM_EW_MX,EW_SERIAL_MX,CUSTOMER_CODE,BRANCH_CODE_MX,DATE_ADDED)
        VALUES
        $ewtarray[$item]");
}
```